# Chainlink transactions stuck on Pending even with subscription funded

Tags: smartcontracts, web3js, chainlink

I have a chainlink subscription on Polygon Mainnet that was working perfectly until I ran out of LINK for my subscription, at which point all transactions for requests on random numbers were put into a pending state.

I have since funded the subscription and new calls to request randomization are working from the contract but the transactions that were put into a pending state above continue to be stuck in there. It has been around an hour and they are not resolving. When I click into the transaction hash it shows successful but the chainlink remains stuck on pending.

[My VRF subscription showing funded and pending transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLeTU.png)

I dont know how to solve these transactions or even cancel them. Please advise!

I have funded the subscription and this has not fixed the issue.